# Is it possible to have 3 horizontal tabs on desktop, then content splits out of the first tab into 5 vertical tabs on mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to break down the amount of information users receive on mobile devices by splitting content out of horizontal tabs into vertical tabs.

I've been playing around on code pen, but so far I'm not having very much luck. It works ok on mobile, content is at least in the right place, but on desktop I cannot get the first tab to open.
Also, I need to make sure only one tab is open at once.

Here is what I've done so far, any suggestions as to what I could try?

http://codepen.io/Han/pen/elKtF

Code

```
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="tab-outter tab-one cf"> 
    <span id='one' class="tab-handle tab-one-handle">Title 1 </span>
    <ul class="tab-content tab-content-one first-tab-desktop">
      <li> 1st Content Here </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-outter tab-two cf  "> 
    <span id='two' class="tab-handle tab-handle-two  first-tab-desktop">Title 2 </span>
    <ul class="tab-content tab-content-two  first-tab-desktop">
      <li> 2nd Content Here </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-outter tab-three  cf "> 
    <span id='three' class="tab-handle tab-handle-three first-tab-desktop">Title 3 </span>
    <ul class="tab-content tab-content-three first-tab-desktop">
      <li>3rd Content Here </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="tab-outter tab-four cf  "> 
    <span id='four' class="tab-handle">Title 4 </span>
    <ul class="tab-content">
      <li> 4th Content Here 
        <div class="faq">
          <h5>Question</h5>
          <p>answer</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-outter tab-five cf  "> 
    <span id='five' class="tab-handle">Title 5 </span>
    <ul class="tab-content">
      <li>5th Content Here </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>


body { 
  font-family: helvectica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.tab-outter {
  border: 1px solid #3e3e3e;

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.tab-handle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px; 
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #0299ea;
  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-top: none;
  }
}

.tab-content-one {
  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    width: 33%;   
  }  
}

.tab-content-two {
  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    top: 60px;
    left: 33%;
    width: 33%;
    display: none;
  }  
}

.tab-handle-two {
  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    top: 30px;
    width: 33%;
    display: none;
  }  
}

.tab-content-three {
  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 66%;
    top: 60px;
    width: 33%;   
  }  
}

.tab-handle-three {
  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 66%;
    top: 30px;
    display: none;
    width: 33%;
  }  
}

.expanded {
  display: block;
}



(function ($) {

  var handle = $('.tab-handle')
  var desktopFirstTab = $('.first-tab-desktop');

  handle.click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.tab-content').toggleClass('expanded');
  });

  tabControl();

  $(window).bind('resize', function () { 
    tabControl();
    console.log($(window).width());
  });


  function tabControl(e) {
    if($(window).width() > 640) {

      $(".tab-one-handle").click(function(e) {
        console.log($(this).siblings());
        desktopFirstTab.toggleClass('expanded');
      });    

      $(".tab-two-handle").click(function(e){

      });
    } 
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: I can't help you with this but responsive design has been around for about 5 years now and there is a plugin called responsive tabs to accordion http://webthemez.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html and there's others too, this one is nice: https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs

Comment: Thanks, I can get my design to go from horizontal to vertical. The problem comes in when I move tabs 2 & 3 into the first tab for desktop. My first tab doesn't open with tab 2 & 3 on click. Also, I need the tabs to open one at a time, with the exception on desktop of 1, 2 and 3 all being open at once. 
Although, the second plugin you have linked has a destroy func, which may be useful. I'll give it a try.